# Is there any way to show the startup params of my process in pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I startup 2 processes.

```sh
# pm2 start main.js -- with_param1
# pm2 start main.js -- with_param2
```

But `pm2 list` can not show what param I passed.
Is there any way to show the startup params of my process?

Answer (score 1):

One of these might be what you're looking for

```
pm2 show <process-name|process-id>
```

or

```
pm2 describe <process-name|process-id>
```